# Facebook Live Video comments sometimes delayed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a service that reads Facebook Live comments once every 30 seconds and the vast majority of the time it works great.  One user just had an issue where during a Live stream the comments were reading fine but then mid-way through the video Facebook was sending back an empty data set for video comments (even though people were still commenting).  For 30 minutes Facebook was not sending comments back.  Then all of a sudden Facebook returned back all of the comments in batch sizes of 25 each subsequent call.  After the service caught up all on the comments Facebook continued returning comments for the rest of the video's life cycle.

I checked rate limiting and the page and app are both well under the rate limits.  Facebook did not report being down for any time from what I could see yesterday.  Has anyone else experienced this behavior before?  If so, is this a Facebook issue or is there something I can do to prevent this from happening again?

Comment: (How) have you verified it was not a problem on the receiving end?

Comment: Good question, I guess I haven't fully verified.  Since this has only happened once that I'm aware of so far and I can't reproduce this on command, there's no way for me to debug it or manually hit the endpoints with Postman to verify.  However in my logs I have it tell me how many new comments it has found and for that 30 minute period it continued to say it 0 new comments found.